# How to write custom mode in ace editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I am working with Angular 1.7.  I have ace-editor in my node_modules folder. Now I want to create custom mode in ace editor. Is it possible that I create a separate javascript file as mode-custom.js and add the code in that and then I imported that mode file in my application?

Comment: Yes, I did it. What part do you have questions about?

Comment: See, my ace editor is part of node_modules..Means I am downloading it as a dependency. So I cant's commit new mode in that. So I was wondering that can I create a new javascript file for new mode separately. Will that work?

Comment: @komeilmajidi : any updates? was your ace editor part of node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `define` or `ace.define` (depending on whether you are using `noconflict` version or not) to define a mode at `ace/mode/<name>` path, and Ace will pick it up when the mode ID for the editor is set to that. See [here](https://github.com/GameMakerDiscord/GMEdit/blob/master/bin/resources/app/plugins/ini-editor/ini-editor.js) for a relatively clean example.